# How can I monitor a directory for newly uploaded files?

Tags: file, windows-services

I need to create a windows service that will monitor a directory for newly uploaded files.
The files will be around 100K to 400K in size.

Is there a chance that my monitoring system will notice a new file, but the file hasn't completetly finished copying over? i.e. it is still streaming in and the EOF hasn't been written yet?

Comment: Please state the language you wish to develop it in as this changes how your question is answered.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a chance that this will happen.  You should upload the file to a temporary directory first, then move it to the directory you're monitoring when the entire file is present on your file system.

Answer (score 2):

Try reading the second tale [here](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/A-Problem-at-the-Personal-Level--More.aspx) and the comments. Essentially, it's as Bill the Lizard said

Answer (score 0):

yes.  With small files the risk is fairly low, but if you want to be certain have it check when it sees a file to make sure it's size stays stable over a second or two.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)?  I've only used this once, but I think you can configure the parameters to tell it what events you want to consider and set up separate handlers for each.  I suspect that the FileSystemWatcher may not even notify you on file creation until the file has been closed, but I haven't tried it.

Note: this is .NET solution.  If you're not using .NET, please disregard.